# Use pycharm for Flexbe

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I've followed the tutorials from http://wiki.ros.org/flexbe/Tutorials so that i could run the hello world behavior inside of the chrome app as well as running it in the console.

Then I started a console which has `catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` sourced and run pycharm. I've added the folder that is created by calling `rosrun flexbe_widget create_repo calibration_controller` to pycharm.

But when I open the file `calibration_controller_behaviors/calibration_controller_flexbe_states/src/calibration_controller_flexbe_states/example_action_state.py` pycharm can't resolve the dependencies `from flexbe_core import EventState, Logger` or `from flexbe_core.proxy import ProxyActionClient`, but can resolve other ros dependencies like `import rospy`.

Why can't pycharm resolve flexbe imports?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with ros kinetic.

Thanks,
Benny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264703/use-pycharm-for-flexbe/) by [bennypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8396/bennypi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-06-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2017-06-26**:
Duplicate discussion from:
https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/34

You might want to edit this question to make it more generic to the use of PyCharm within the ROS workspace with Catkin and setup.py usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to [flexbe devs on github](https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/34), the following steps resolve the issue:

1. Open PyCharm's settings
2. Open your project on the left of the settings window
3. Open Project Structure
4. Select your `[your_project_prefix]_flexbe_states` project that is created when running `rosrun flexbe_widget create_repo [your_project_prefix]`
5. Click on Add Content Root
6. Select `xenials_ws/src/flexbe_behavior_engine`
7. Mark that folder as source
8. Mark the subdirectory `flexbe_core` as source
9. Mark the subdirectory `flexbe_core/src` as source
10. Click on OK and wait until PyCharm's triggers run and find the flexbe sources.

---

Originally posted by [bennypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8396/bennypi/) with karma: 48 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2